# JBoss Security Elytron Using Credential Stores for RARs

Tags: jboss, rar, elytron

I am using JBoss 7.3. I have wmq RAR and I want to connect wmq using Password from Elytron Security Credential Store. I tried to do it via configuration from Admin Console with Credential Store authentication context and config, but no success. Although I could set up using admin console for DB passwords. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For your WMQ JCA configuration, you will need to add the section:

```
  <security>
       <elytron-enabled />
  </security>
```

So your configuration will look something like:

```
  <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0">
     <resource-adapters>
         <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar" statistics-enabled="true">
             <archive>
                 wmq.jmsra.rar
             </archive>
             <transaction-support>NoTransaction</transaction-support>
             <connection-definitions>
                 <connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/MQCF" tracking="false" pool-name="mq-pool">
                     <security>
                        <elytron-enabled />
                     </security>
                     <config-property name="channel">
                         CHANNEL
                     </config-property>
```

Comment: Thanks Doug for the response. In this subsystem configuration, where should I pass the credentials store config from which I will be retrieving the alias information. Is it possible if you could highlight that as well. I mean a sample connection-definition section.